# How do I compare objects in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a data class written in Kotlin which has server error objects.

How can I check which object it is?

I can do it in Kotlin like this

```kotlin
when (failure) {
    is Failure.ServerError -> test()//do something
    is Failure.ServerErrorConflict -> test()//do something
}
```

The same thing I want to do it in Java:

```java
switch (failure) {
    case failure == Failure.ServerErrorConflict:
        break;
}
```

But I get an error `expression expected`

This is my data class

```kotlin
sealed class Failure {
    object NetworkConnection : Failure()
    object ServerError : Failure()
    object ServerErrorConflict : Failure()

    /** * Extend this class for feature specific failures.*/
    abstract class FeatureFailure : Failure()
}
```

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: `instanceof` xxx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally in java, object references are compared to type using `instanceof` binary operator.

In future versions of Java, for some types, if-else conditions with `instanceof` equality check is not needed and a switch can be used. The *sealed classes* feature providing this benefit is being [previewed currently in Java 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360), and being [previewed again in the upcoming Java 16](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/397).

```java
    switch (failure) {
        case NetworkConnection nc -> <do the required operation>
        case ServerError se -> <do the required operation>
        case ServerErrorConflict sec -> <do the required operation>
    }
```

### Note - switch expressions

- `break` is not needed(will not fall through)
- value can be returned

[Java SE Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/switch-expressions.html)